# PHPExcel Conditional Formatting inside loop

Tags: php, formatting, phpexcel

I'm trying to apply PHPExcel conditional formatting to all the cells in columm B with a value under 50. I took the example from the developer documentation but so far I can't make it work. Any ideas?

Here is the conditional:

```
$objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional(); 
$objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS);
$objConditional1->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_LESSTHAN);

$objConditional1->addCondition('50'); 
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED); 
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Here is the loop:

```
$rowCount = 3;
foreach ($biocount as $value) {

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $value);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'. $rowCount)->getFont()->setSize(14);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'. $rowCount)->setConditionalStyles($objConditional1);

$rowCount++;
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setConditionalStyles() expects an array of conditional styles, not a single conditional style object

```
/**
 * Set Conditional Styles. Only used on supervisor.
 *
 * @param PHPExcel_Style_Conditional[] $pValue Array of condtional styles
 * @return PHPExcel_Style
 */
```

e.g.

```
$rowCount = 3;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $value);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'. $rowCount)
        ->getFont()->setSize(14);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'. $rowCount)
        ->setConditionalStyles(array($objConditional1));
    $rowCount++;
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that, rather than having the overhead of setting the conditional styles for each individual cell within the loop, you could use the duplicateConditionalStyle() method to apply the styling to a range of cells in a single step once you've finished looping

```
$rowCount = 3;
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $value);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'. $rowCount)
        ->getFont()->setSize(14);
    $rowCount++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->duplicateConditionalStyle(
        array($objConditional1), 
        'B3:B' .($rowCount - 1)
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. Very explanatory answer.

Comment: How can we copy conditional formatting and apply to other cells from a loaded template in phpexcel?